# JavaScript AWS Client gateway API x-api-key issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

We are invoking AWS REST API using JavaScript AWS Client Gateway API on nodejs server. We have private vpc published API which require API Key in header. Here is the code.
I have hard coed API Key for testing purpose in below script.

```
    var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
let awsbody = JSON.parse(process.argv[2].split('\\').join('') || '{}');

var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    invokeUrl: awsbody.endPoint, // REQUIRED
    accessKey: awsbody.awsAccessKey, // REQUIRED
    secretKey: awsbody.awsSecreteKey, // REQUIRED
    region: awsbody.awsRegion,
    apiKey: 'vs2i50xvo4',
    retryCondition: (err) => { 
        return err.response && err.response.status === 500;
    }
});

var pathParams = awsbody.awsPathParams;

var pathTemplate = awsbody.awsPathTemplate; // '/api/v1/sites'
var method = awsbody.method; // 'POST';
var additionalParams = { queryParams: awsbody.awsAdditionalParams }; //queryParams if any
//var additionalParams = {};

var body = awsbody.requestBody;
var output = {};


apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
    .then(function(result) {
        // return JSON.parse(result.data);
        output.status = result.response.data.status,
            output.message = result.response.data.message,
            output.responsecode = result.response.status,
            output.responsetext = result.response.statusText;
        output.header = result.response.headers;
        console.log(output)

    }).catch(function(result) {

        output.status = result.response.data.status,
            output.message = result.response.data.message,
            output.responsecode = result.response.status,
            output.responsetext = result.response.statusText,
            output.header = result.response.headers;
        console.log(output)
            //console.log("********** Output **************")
            //console.log(result)
            //return result;
    });
```

When trying to execute the code, getting below error. Not sure, if anything wrong in above code.

```
{ status: undefined,
  message: 'Forbidden',
  responsecode: 403,
  responsetext: 'Forbidden',
  header:
   { server: 'Server',
     date: 'Tue, 12 Mar 2019 00:00:37 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'content-length': '24',
     'x-amzn-requestid': 'ddce6604-4459-11e9-a23b-d1e9d6814b3a',
     'x-amzn-errortype': 'ForbiddenException',
     'x-amz-apigw-id': 'WZt53GORPHcFebA=',
     connection: 'close' } }
```

Comment: have you set appropiate CORS accept-* headers for the request?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved now. It was not CORS issue but header issue. I am passing key in additional parameter as header tag and it worked as expected.

```
 var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
let awsbody = JSON.parse(process.argv[2].split('\\').join('') || '{}');

var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    invokeUrl: awsbody.endPoint, // REQUIRED
    accessKey: awsbody.awsAccessKey, // REQUIRED
    secretKey: awsbody.awsSecreteKey, // REQUIRED
    region: awsbody.awsRegion,
    retryCondition: (err) => { 
        return err.response && err.response.status === 500;
    }
});

var pathParams = awsbody.awsPathParams;

var pathTemplate = awsbody.awsPathTemplate; // '/api/v1/sites'
var method = awsbody.method; // 'POST';
var additionalParams = {headers: { "x-apigw-api-id": 'vs2i50xvo4'}};

var body = awsbody.requestBody;
var output = {};


apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
    .then(function(result) {
        // return JSON.parse(result.data);
        output.status = result.response.data.status,
            output.message = result.response.data.message,
            output.responsecode = result.response.status,
            output.responsetext = result.response.statusText;
        output.header = result.response.headers;
        console.log(output)

    }).catch(function(result) {

        output.status = result.response.data.status,
            output.message = result.response.data.message,
            output.responsecode = result.response.status,
            output.responsetext = result.response.statusText,
            output.header = result.response.headers;
        console.log(output)
            //console.log("********** Output **************")
            //console.log(result)
            //return result;
    });
```